# Trying to update two django forms at once

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to use an UpdateView in Django to update two forms simultaneously. I have the get method working properly, but when I submit the update, the post method creates a new instance of the forms. How can I grab the forms from the get method and update them without creating a new instance? Everything is redirecting fine and I am getting no errors.

```
class MotionStudyInstanceUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = MotionStudyInstance
fields = ['height', 'weight', 'skin_type_score', 'fitzpatrick_skin_type']
template_name = 'data/motionstudyinstance_update.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('data:motion-studies')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    pass

def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    item = MotionStudyInstance.objects.get(id=pk)
    general_info = item.general_info
    form = MotionStudyInstanceForm(
        initial={'height': item.height, 'weight': item.weight, 'skin_type_score': item.skin_type_score,
                 'fitzpatrick_skin_type': item.fitzpatrick_skin_type})
    form_two = GeneralInfoForm(initial={'case_report_form_number': general_info.case_report_form_number,
                                        'form_type': general_info.form_type,
                                        'study_start_date': general_info.study_start_date,
                                        'signed_consent': general_info.signed_consent,
                                        'gender': general_info.gender,
                                        'miscellaneous_notes': general_info.miscellaneous_notes,
                                        'adverse_events': general_info.adverse_events})
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'foreign_form': form_two})

def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MotionStudyInstanceForm(request.POST)
        foreign_form = GeneralInfoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and foreign_form.is_valid():
            general_info = foreign_form.save()
            user_form = form.save(commit=False)
            user_form.general_info = general_info
            user_form.save()
            return redirect('data:motion-studies')
    else:
        form = MotionStudyInstanceForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class MotionStudyInstanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = MotionStudyInstance
    exclude = ('general_info',)
    widgets = {
        'validation_status': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'author': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'sibling': forms.HiddenInput()
    }

class GeneralInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = GeneralInfo
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'form_type': forms.HiddenInput(),
    }
```

Comment: please post your forms

Comment: forms.py is posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should be using the instance parameter on the forms.
So you can update it on the post, and display it on the get

something like this:

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    item = MotionStudyInstance.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MotionStudyInstanceForm(request.POST, instance=item)
```

Comment: What about the general info form? How can I grab the pk for that form from kwargs? The view displays both forms at the same time

Comment: the general info would have the instance =  item.general_info

Comment: Duh. I should’ve known that. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I am not currently at my computer. I will get back to you as soon as I get back to my dorm. I can’t see why that wouldn’t work.

Comment: Update: it worked! Just had to remember to set values for hidden fields or they were overwritten for some reason. Thanks for the help!